# Shiny: Is there a way to trigger an observeEvent() by switching between tabsPanel()'s

Tags: r, shiny, notifications, tabs

I'm working on a Shiny app and I would like to know if it's possible or if anyone else has been able to trigger an `observeEvent()` by switching between `tabPanel()`.

I have had experience in enabling and disabling the `tabPanel()` once certain actions are executed thanks to @SriPaladugu [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382091/how-to-disable-a-tabpanel-in-shinydashboard/37398020#37398020) and @DeanAttali shinyjs package but I don't know the extent of these two methods/package when it comes to answering my own question.

I need to trigger an `observeEvent()` in order to execute `removeNotification()` and remove any warnings windows when switching between tabs.

The way I pictured of doing this was something like:

```r
    observeEvent(input$tabSwitch, {
        removeNotification(previous.warning.message)
    })
```

However, there is no way to make switching tabs an eventExpr thus making the code above exectuable

If anyone has done this or has knowledge on how to do this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried providing an `id` in the `tabsetPanel` and using `observeEvent(input$tabset_id, {...})`?

Comment: @ClancyStats I have not but it seems that it might work. Let me try it right quick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments you'll have to provide an `id` to the `tabsetPanel`.

Here is a working example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(id = "tabSwitch",
      tabPanel("Tab 1", br(), "Tab 1 content"),
      tabPanel("Tab 2", br(), "Tab 2 content"),
      tabPanel("Tab 3", br(), "Tab 3 content")
    ), br(),
    actionButton("warningBtn", "Generate Warning")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$warningBtn, {
    showNotification(ui = paste(Sys.time(), " - Warning!"), duration = NULL, closeButton = FALSE, id = "previousWarningMessage", type = "warning")
  })

  observeEvent(input$tabSwitch, {
    print(paste("You clicked tab:", input$tabSwitch))
    removeNotification("previousWarningMessage")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```