# Shiny: Disable tabPanel() using shinyjs

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I'm using @SriPaladugu's answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382091/how-to-disable-a-tabpanel-in-shinydashboard/) to disable a `tabPanel()` and I noticed that it doesn't work if there exist a space in `tabPanel(title,...)`. They wrote their own JavaScript code and used `shinyjs` to enable/disable panels and I'm not familiar with JavaScript code to fix this issue. Their code that does this is stored in the object `jscode`; how can the code be modified to account for spaces in `tabPanel(title,...)`?

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jscode <- "
shinyjs.disableTab = function(name) {
var tab = $('.nav li a[data-value=' + name + ']');
tab.bind('click.tab', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
return false;
});
tab.addClass('disabled');
}

shinyjs.enableTab = function(name) {
var tab = $('.nav li a[data-value=' + name + ']');
tab.unbind('click.tab');
tab.removeClass('disabled');
}
"
css <- "
.nav li a.disabled {
background-color: #aaa !important;
color: #333 !important;
cursor: not-allowed !important;
border-color: #aaa !important;
}"



ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = c("disableTab","enableTab")),
  shinyjs::inlineCSS(css),
  navbarPage("Test",id="navbarPage",
             tabPanel("FirstTab", id = "first_tab",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(),
                        mainPanel()
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("Secondtab", id = "second_tab",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(),
                        mainPanel()
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("Third tab", id = "third_tab",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(),
                        mainPanel()
                      )
             )
             )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # disable tabs Exposure, Covariate, and Construct on page load
  shinyjs::js$disableTab("Secondtab")
  shinyjs::js$disableTab("Third tab")
})

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I think the problem is that variable names can't have spaces in javascript. Try something like this `tabPanel(title = "Third panel", value = "third_panel", ...)`, maybe it works.
EDIT: I'm not familiar with JS either, but that is something I would try.

Comment: `value` The value that should be sent when tabsetPanel reports that this tab is selected. If omitted and tabsetPanel has an id, then the title will be used...

Comment: Thank you to both of you. It is indeed the `value` name I should be using

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can simplify your code, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703241/activate-tabpanel-from-another-tabpanel) and the documentation of `shinyjs::disable()`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

css <- "
.nav li a.disabled {
background-color: #aaa !important;
color: #333 !important;
cursor: not-allowed !important;
border-color: #aaa !important;
}"

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::inlineCSS(css),
  navbarPage("Test",id="navbarPage",
             tabPanel("FirstTab", id = "first_tab",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(),
                        mainPanel()
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("Secondtab", id = "second_tab",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(),
                        mainPanel()
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("Third tab", id = "third_tab",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(),
                        mainPanel()
                      )
             )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # disable tabs Exposure, Covariate, and Construct on page load
  shinyjs::disable(selector = '.navbar-nav a[data-value="Secondtab"')
  shinyjs::disable(selector = '.navbar-nav a[data-value="Third tab"')
})

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Just to complete this answer, to obtain `data-value`, open the app in browser, do Ctrl+Shift+C, hover the tab you want and check its `data-value` argument in the Inspector.